# How to build that query (sum,group by)

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

I have the following table

```
 #   amount   type
 1     10      0
 1     10      0
 1     5       1
 1     5       1
 2     10      0
 2     10      0
 2     5       1
 2     5       1
```

*where 0 means cash and 1 means credit in the type column*

The problem is to find the total of cash usages and credit usages and total amount for every ID.

I'm looking for query that gets following result

```
 #   cash credit total
 1    20    10    30 
 2    20    10    30
```

I would like to use one query if it's possible

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT id, 
SUM(CASE WHEN type = 0 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as "cash",
SUM(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as "credit", 
SUM(amount) as "total"
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  num,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type=0 THEN amount END) cash,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type=1 THEN amount END) credit,
  SUM(amount) total
FROM
  yourtable
GROUP BY num
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,
       sum(amount) as "total",
       CASE WHEN type = 0 THEN amount ELSE 0 END as "cash",
       CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END as "credit",
  from table
 group by id
```